# Is a current source a single component or the same as a voltage source?

Tags: current-source

Is a current source a component on its own or is it the same as a cell?

If the two are different why does the current source supply only current and a cell supply both current and voltage?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=current+source&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNQloJj7g7CiGr91N1gJiffSb97kUw:1580867759399&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIh_Gpp7nnAhXbBc0KHeSoBw0Q_AUoAXoECDkQAw&biw=1533&bih=881

Comment: The current source can also supply voltage. Consider how both sources behave when the load is short connection, resistor and open circuit.

Comment: How can a current source supply a voltage, is it by converting to voltage source as in thevenin and norton theorem

Comment: Because a real "current source" is nothing else than a voltage source with a very large source resistance (see jusaca`s answer), it can cause a voltage across the load resistor due to the well-known voltage-divider principle. (Note, it is the circuit called "current source" and NOT the current itself that causes the voltage across the load).

Comment: While it touches some very basic circuit theory and most of us here wonder why someone would not know that, I don't think it is a stupid question. So voting to leave it open.

Answer (score 0):

Whether something is acting as a voltage source or current source is only determined by what parameter they try to keep constant at the output, but both will deliver current as well as voltage (Ohm's law!).

**In a voltage source**, the voltage at the output is kept at a constant level and the source will (ideally) deliver as much current as is needed to drop that voltage over the load resistance. If there is an open circuit, the voltage source will deliver no current at all, but if there is load with the resistance R, than the current will be \$ I = \frac{U}{R} \$.

**In a current source**, the current at the output is kept at a constant level and the source will (again, ideally) supply whatever voltage is needed to keep that current flowing. With a very small load resistance the output voltage will be very small, with a higher resistance the voltage has to increase to keep the current flowing (again, \$ I = \frac{U}{R} \$).

In reality both sources obviously are limited. With increasing load resistance a current source will reach the maximum voltage at some place and than the current will not be kept constant anymore. The opposite is true for voltage sources: With very low load resistances the source won't be able to supply as much current as is needed to keep the voltage constant.

Circuit wise, you can look at a current source like a voltage source with indefinite (or really large) internal resistance and an indefinite (or really large) voltage. This will drop almost all voltage on the internal resistance and whether or not the load resistance is changing does not really change anything in regards of the current flow.
See on the left a load of 1 Ohm and on the right a resistance of 1kOhm. How much the current of the current source is changing with a change in resistance determines the quality of the source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKLjzC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In practise this is not done with ridiculously large component values, but with an active control of the output (a transistor at the output of the supply is controlling the output resistance).

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the **ideal** sources that are used in circuit analysis problems then you need different definitions of their behavior.

An **ideal current source** constrains the current flowing through it. The voltage across an ideal current source is determined by the rest of the circuit.

An **ideal voltage source** constrains the voltage across its terminals. The current flowing through it is determined by the rest of the circuit.

Either of the ideal sources may supply power to a circuit or absorb power from the circuit. If a positive current is entering the higher voltage terminal then the source is absorbing power. If positive current is leaving the higher voltage terminal then the source is providing power.